# What is the better and secure way to login and logout in PHP?

Tags: php, html, authentication

I'm a beginner in PHP. my login page is a ***login.html*** page and it posts inputted data to a ***logged.php*** page. and in this page it checks inputted data with my DB and if it was true, it showed this ***logedd.php*** page or if not, it returns to ***login.html*** page with the code below:

```
header('Location:Login.html');
```

and also when I press Logout icon in ***logged.php***, it returns to ***login.html*** by a href link in it. like this:

```
<a href="login.php" target="_self"> press to logout </a>
```

Now my question is, Is this login and logout way secure or not? if not please describe why and how to make it secure? thanks.

Comment: You can use a session or a cookie to identify if a user is logged in. And then destroy the session or the cookie to logout

Comment: can you describe how can I use cookies?

Comment: Use session. check this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: @Jerrak0s read the question carefully and answer it!

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a login system at all, just a password protected page.

Comment: @Quentin I agree with you. but is it the secure way for protecting the page?

Comment: @illusionist_yahya do you know how to use session?

Comment: @0bijanmortazavi — Nothing about what has been described is insecure, but the question doesn't describe most of the system.

Comment: please read the question completely then add comment! I asked Is it secure or not??? @Quentin yes I have a password protected.

Comment: I just noticed. Please don't use cookie for login that introduces only security problems. Sensitive information should be stored server-side. Use session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work this way. You look up your credentials in database if they match with your form input you make a session. If session exist you have additional content. This is a very simple description of how it works.

Oh and about security. look up these function. password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAUT); for inserting password. When you want to compare password from database with form input you use password_verify($inputpassword, $databasepassword). Also use htmlentities and bind parameters.

Comment: thanks it was helpful.